# Design issue in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter. I have created a Login page. I want to add a loader until it check the internet is present in my device or not. But every time in my code the `NoInternet` widgets is loading for a fraction of a second. I am very much confused.

```
class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});
  @override
  State<MainApp> createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  String? sUsername;
  bool isInternetAvailable = false;
  bool isLoading = true;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeApp();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeApp() async {
    await _checkInternetAndUser();
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _checkInternetAndUser() async {
    bool isConnected = await NetworkService.checkInternetConnection();
    setState(() {
      isInternetAvailable = isConnected;
    });
    _checkNewOrOldUser();
  }

  void _checkNewOrOldUser() async {
    sUsername = await loadData('username');
    setState(() {});
  }

  void refreshApp() {
    _checkInternetAndUser();
  }

  Future<String?> loadData(String username) async {}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isLoading) {
      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Daily Pay',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: theme,
        home: const Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      if (!isInternetAvailable) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Daily Pay',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: theme,
          home: NoInternetConnection(
            onRefresh: refreshApp,
          ),
        );
      } else {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Daily Pay',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: theme,
          home:
              sUsername == null ? const loginScreen() : const DashBoardScreen(),
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: add some delay here,  Future<void> _checkInternetAndUser() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500)).then((value) {
      bool isConnected = await NetworkService.checkInternetConnection();
      isInternetAvailable = isConnected;
      setState(() {});
      _checkNewOrOldUser();
    });
  }

Comment: I think you code is correct. Is there something which you miss telling here?

Comment: your initial state is `bool isInternetAvailable = false;` and you wonder why your ui says no internet for a split second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This!

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
      bool isConnected = await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection;
      setState(() {
        isInternetAvailable = isConnected;
        isLoading = false;
      });
      _checkNewOrOldUser();
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```